# How to control access to a InfoPath Form Button that is controlled by a SharePoint Security Group

Tags: button, sharepoint, infopath

I was wondering if there is away to control a InfoPath Form Button enable it if you are in the Security Group and disable it if you are not in the SharePoint Security Group.

Client does not want to use the list method.

Answer (score 0):

Well it isn't possible. However there is a workaround I sometimes use:
You create a list and add only  one item. Give unique permissions on that particular item for only the Group.

Then in InfoPath create a Data Connection on that list and check with rules if the ID is present of the data result (or check on some value if you want). If user is in the group then it will get that one record. If not the user it will result in no records.